# Python reading a text file and loading a pre made array/list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a program in python that will take a pre made selection of lists from a file and convert them into a variable.

My current code for this is

```
datain = open("test.json", "r") #open file storing questions and awnsers
datause = datain.readlines() #get data loaded for use
```

which is later followed by

```
for i in range(0, numquest):
    x = []
    print("Question " + str(( i + 1 )))
    x = datause[i]
    print(x[1])
    awns = input(x[2])
```

Which returns

```
"
W
```

The content of my file that i'm reading from is

```
["What type of device is a mouse? : ", "1) Input 2) Storage 3) Output :", "1", "1) Input"]
```

Which is what i would like to load as a list/array

```
["What type of device is a mouse? : ", "1) Input 2) Storage 3) Output :", "1", "1) Input"]
["What type of storage is a hard drive? : ", "1) Optical 2) Magnetic 3) Read-Only : ", "2", "2) Magnetic"]
["How is eight(8) represented in binary? : ", "1) 1111 2) 1001 3) 1000 : ", "3", "3) 1000"]
```

are the example questions i am currently using for testing in my test.json file

Comment: How does your file look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `print(x[1])` , it only prints the character at index 1 , I do not think that is what you want.

If what you want is to print the first element of the list first and then in `input(x[2])` you want the second element of the list.

Like myershustinc said, use `json.load()` to load the data into datause object, and then iterate through each list in datause , and then print first and second element for it.

Example -

```
for l in datause:
    for i in range(0, numquest):
        print("Question " + str(( i + 1 )))
        print(l[0])
        awns = input(l[1])
```

I do not think you need `x` . Also, please note python is `0` indexed, `0 -> index of first element`.

Also, seems like your json file is corrupted, try with this content -

```
[["What type of device is a mouse? : ", "1) Input 2) Storage 3) Output :", "1", "1) Input"],
["What type of storage is a hard drive? : ", "1) Optical 2) Magnetic 3) Read-Only : ", "2", "2) Magnetic"],
["How is eight(8) represented in binary? : ", "1) 1111 2) 1001 3) 1000 : ", "3", "3) 1000"]]
```

Comment: using both of the answers provided has solved the problem where it only prints the first few characters, however the intent was for the program to cycle through a selection of lists/arrays each on a new line in the json file, using these methods causes a rather large list of errors. Can you give any advice on solving this?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\program\pyth\school\quiz.py", line 29, in <module>
    datause = json.load(datain)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\json\__init__.py", line 271, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\json\__init__.py", line 316, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\json\decoder.py", line 354, in decode
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
ValueError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 - line 2 column 93 (char 91 - 183)

Comment: LIke I asked as a comment in the question , can you please the question with a sample of the file

Comment: The `[` and `]` and all are part of the file? Can you just copy paste the file here?

Comment: That is the entire content of the file, I generated the file by creating the list/array and using json.dumps()

Comment: Updated the answer, please check.

Comment: The method you suggested causes error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\program\pyth\schooquiz.py", line 29, in <module>
    datause = json.load(datain)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\json\__init__.py", line 271, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\json\__init__.py", line 316, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\json\decoder.py", line 354, in decode
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
ValueError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 - line 3 column 92 (char 91 - 289)

Comment: Unsure how to proceed from here, should i supply more of my programs code to help you understand what i'm trying to achieve?

Comment: Seems like some issue occured which corrupted your json dump, can you try the latest json content i updated in my answer

Comment: Thank you for the help, I had one small issue with your final response but that was resolved by removing the for loop statement

Answer (score 2):

For a JSON file, you could just use `json.load`:

```
import json
with open("test.json", "r") as datain:
    datause = json.load(datain)
```

At this point `datause` is an array containing whatever was in your JSON file.

More on the `json` library in [the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/json.html).